# Deflection issue in platformer game programmed with Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, 2d-games

I'm trying to program a simple platformer game with very accurate movement using Unreal Engine 4 (4.22 release). It took some inspiration from games like Super Meat Boy or Celeste. 
I'm using the APaperCharacter that uses UCharacterMovementComponent, but I'm not very satisfied of it.
Particularly I would like to avoid the deflection that is used in UCharacterMovementComponent::PhysFalling() method:

```
const FVector OldHitNormal = Hit.Normal;
    const FVector OldHitImpactNormal = Hit.ImpactNormal;        
    FVector Delta = ComputeSlideVector(Adjusted, 1.f - Hit.Time, OldHitNormal, Hit);

    // Compute velocity after deflection (only gravity component for RootMotion)
    if (subTimeTickRemaining > KINDA_SMALL_NUMBER && !bJustTeleported)
    {
      const FVector NewVelocity = (Delta / subTimeTickRemaining);
      Velocity = HasAnimRootMotion() && !CurrentRootMotion.HasOverrideVelocity() ? FVector(Velocity.X, Velocity.Y, NewVelocity.Z) : NewVelocity;
    }
```

I recorded a video to show you the behavior I would like to prevent:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fko1aPl-Vdo

I'm thinking to create my personal movement component that derives UCharacterMovementComponent in order to override the ComputeSlideVector() method, but I don't know if it is the best idea to resolve this issue.
I would like to have your opionion and I would like to know if I can simply solve the problem changing some parameters by editor.

Comment: Overriding the component is a no brainier really if you want to full control over character movement, you'd likely run into more problems trying to mould the inbuilt character mover. Celeste's movement was written from scratch. Also in general there's a ton of classes, especially gameplay classes in Unreal that can be overriden, which is great as it can make writing certain games feasible without having to build from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually decided to create my own class derived from UCharacterMovementComponent.
I solved the issue I described in my question overriding the UCharacterMovementComponent ::ComputeSlideVector() method:

```
FVector UMyMovementComponent::ComputeSlideVector(const FVector& Delta, const float Time, const FVector& Normal, const FHitResult& Hit) const
{
    FVector Result = Super::ComputeSlideVector(Delta, Time, Normal, Hit);

    if (Hit.bBlockingHit)
    {
        float Angle = FVector::DotProduct(Hit.Normal, FVector::DownVector);
        if (Angle > KINDA_SMALL_NUMBER) // if the collision normal points downwards
        {
            Result.X = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    return Result;
}
```